# How to get dictionary value from key in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new list from a list of dictionary items.
Below is an example of 1 dictionary item.

```
{'id': 'bitcoin',
  'symbol': 'btc',
  'name': 'Bitcoin',
  'current_price': 11907.43,
  'market_cap': 220817187069,
  'market_cap_rank': 1}
```

I want the list to just be of the id item. So what I am trying to achieve is a list with items {'bitcoin', 'etc', 'etc}

Comment: `[d['id'] for d in list_of_dicts]`?

Comment: You can access the value from the key, but you need the exact name of the key. If you don't need it for any key and only these keys then I can give you an answer, but if you need if for any key I can't help you.

Comment: @marktilbrook ```[d['id'] for d in list_of_dicts]``` would work as most answers suggest, but this would throw an error if there's a dict that doesn't have ```id``` as key. Shouldn't be the accepted answer imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
my_list = [{'id': 'bitcoin', 'symbol': 'btc', ...}, ...]
[d['id'] for d in my_list]
```

Which translates to : for each dictionary in my_list, extract the 'id' key.

Answer (score 1):

```py
list = [ i['id'] for i in list_of_dict]
```

this should help

Answer (score 1):

Simple and readable code that solves the purpose:

```
main_list = []
for item in main_dict:
    main_list.append(item.get("id", None))
print(main_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
id_list = [d["id"] for d in dictlist ]
```

This should work for you